# VIM behavior in Linux VM

Tags: gvim, linux-debian

The GVim window is having screen refresh issues in my vmware virtual machine. The problem is very evident when I scroll pages or go to a line or search for words. Pressing Ctrl-k repaints the screen and if I navigate the document up/down line by line, it clears up.

The VM itself has sufficient resources and nothing is running in the background. OS: Linux Mint 17.2. This is an irritating problem, and affects particularly while doing find/replace as the screen will only show the words are found.

Note, I tried to get a screen shot of the GVim window, but the very act of Alt-PrtScn refreshes the window and the buffer appears. This problem is absent when opening vim on a bash terminal.

Comment: Looks like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018843/gvim-redraw-issues-with-virtual-box-and-windows-7-host/32468637#32468637

Comment: Problem is similar or same. I do not use compiz and using Mate.  The sync issues does not happen with any other apps

Comment: Yes, for the record the Issue its issue 91 on the bug tracker, it sounds like a graphics driver bug,  but I don't know of any real solution to this problem.

Comment: Could this be mitigated with, say a better graphics card or is it in the guts of the software between Windows and Linux ? I am still using the native Intel graphics driver with motherboard that came with i7 processor

Comment: I honestly don't know.